# How to format all files in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, formatting

With previous versions of Visual Studio, I used [Kevin Pilch-Bisson's script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kevinpilchbisson/archive/2004/05/17/133371.aspx) to format all C# files in my solution.

VS2012 dropped macro support, so that doesn't work any more.

How can I easily format all my documents in VS2012?

Comment: I posted this question to document the solution I found. But maybe there are other good ideas out there?

Comment: can you mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 28):

Open <kbd>Tools</kbd>-><kbd>Library Package Manager</kbd>-><kbd>Package Manager Console</kbd>, and run the command below. At the end, all documents will be open in the IDE. (Low-RAM machines will have problems with large solutions.) Changed files will be 
modified in the IDE, and not saved to disk. You can Save All, then Close All if you're ready.

VS2012 removed the VB-like macro language that existed in previous version of 
Visual Studio. However, the underlying DTE interface is still there, and you 
can reach it via PowerShell, in the Package Manager Console

The weird GUID passed to [`ProjectItem.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.open.aspx) 
is [`Constants.vsViewKindCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.constants.vsviewkindcode.aspx).

Normally I'd split this in to multiple lines, but the Package Manager Console 
doesn't support line continuation.

You can find the latest version at https://gist.github.com/JayBazuzi/9e0de544cdfe0c7a4358

```
function f($projectItems) { $projectItems | ? { $_.Name.EndsWith( ".cs" ) } | % { $win = $_.Open('{7651A701-06E5-11D1-8EBD-00A0C90F26EA}') ; $win.Activate() ; $DTE.ExecuteCommand('Edit.FormatDocument') } ; if ($projectItems) { $projectItems | % { f($_.projectItems) } } }

$dte.Solution.Projects | % { f($_.ProjectItems) }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work when your projects are inside solution folders... I'm not familiar enough with Powershell to suggest an improvement unfortunately.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Great catch! Yes, it will need to iterate recursively if `$_` has any `ProjectItems`. You could write a recursive function, or perhaps use a closure. If no one else gets to it first, I'll look at it later.

Comment: @Anthony: I have updated it to recurse. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Here is a small merge request to exclude auto-generated files when formatting code ("*.Designer.cs"):
https://gist.github.com/ubikuity/62335a46d4439b94a034

Answer (score 11):

Here's an update to the existing script which works on very large solutions.

It opens each file, formats it, then saves and closes the file rather than leaving it open. It also skips ".designer." files, since these should generally be left alone.

In recent versions of Visual Studio (after 2017), copy the script to a ps1 file, then in the Package Manager Console run `. C:\path\to\the.ps1` to invoke it. 
(It works in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 to copy and paste it directly into the Package Manager Console.)

**BE WARNED:** Pasting this code into your console will *immediately* open and format every C# file in your entire solution, saving each modified file without asking. It might be a good idea to branch first...

```
function FormatItems($projectItems) {
    $projectItems |
    % {
        # Write-Host "    Examining item: $($_.Name)";

        if ($_.Name -and $_.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".cs") `
            -and (-not $_.Name.ToLower().Contains(".designer."))) {

            $win = $_.Open('{7651A701-06E5-11D1-8EBD-00A0C90F26EA}');
            $win.Activate();

            $dte.ExecuteCommand('Edit.FormatDocument');

            if (!$_.Saved) {
                Write-Host "    Saving modified file: $($_.Name)";
                $dte.ExecuteCommand('File.SaveSelectedItems');
            }

            $dte.ExecuteCommand('Window.CloseDocumentWindow');
        }

        if ($_.ProjectItems -and ($_.ProjectItems.Count -gt 0)) {
            # Write-Host "    Opening sub-items of $($_.Name)";

            FormatItems($_.ProjectItems);
        }
    };
}

$dte.Solution.Projects | % {
    Write-Host "-- Project: $($_.Name)";

    FormatItems($_.ProjectItems)
}
;
```

Comment: This does not seem to work when the root of your solution consists of solution folders instead of projects.

Comment: In it's current form this cannot be copied and pasted in to VS 2017, gives errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496), a free plugin for VS2012. That allow you to clean, reorganize your code. I always use it before checking my code with StyleCop

Comment: While CodeMaid might be a great tool, by default it does a lot more than the question asked, applying a lot more cleanup than Visual Studio's built-in code formatting. This may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ReSharper's Code Cleanup](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Running_Code_Cleanup.html). Looks like this can work on a whole solution at once.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant of the previous two answers that users may find helpful... definitely could be further improved and simplified. This not only formats `.cs` files but also `.json`, `.cshtml`, `.js`, and `.css`.

```
function f($projectItems) { $projectItems | ? { $_.Name -ne $null -and $_.Name.EndsWith( ".cs" ) } | % { $win = $_.Open('{7651A701-06E5-11D1-8EBD-00A0C90F26EA}') ; $win.Activate() ; $DTE.ExecuteCommand('Edit.FormatDocument') } ; if ($projectItems) { $projectItems | % { f($_.projectItems) } } }

$dte.Solution.Projects | % { f($_.ProjectItems) }

function f($projectItems) { $projectItems | ? { $_.Name -ne $null -and $_.Name.EndsWith( ".json" ) } | % { $win = $_.Open('{7651A701-06E5-11D1-8EBD-00A0C90F26EA}') ; $win.Activate() ; $DTE.ExecuteCommand('Edit.FormatDocument') } ; if ($projectItems) { $projectItems | % { f($_.projectItems) } } }

$dte.Solution.Projects | % { f($_.ProjectItems) }

function f($projectItems) { $projectItems | ? { $_.Name -ne $null -and $_.Name.EndsWith( ".cshtml" ) } | % { $win = $_.Open('{7651A701-06E5-11D1-8EBD-00A0C90F26EA}') ; $win.Activate() ; $DTE.ExecuteCommand('Edit.FormatDocument') } ; if ($projectItems) { $projectItems | % { f($_.projectItems) } } }

$dte.Solution.Projects | % { f($_.ProjectItems) }

function f($projectItems) { $projectItems | ? { $_.Name -ne $null -and $_.Name.EndsWith( ".js" ) -and (-not $_.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.Contains("common")) -and (-not $_.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.Contains("Content")) -and (-not $_.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.Contains("Scripts")) } | % { $win = $_.Open('{7651A701-06E5-11D1-8EBD-00A0C90F26EA}') ; $win.Activate() ; $DTE.ExecuteCommand('Edit.FormatDocument') } ; if ($projectItems) { $projectItems | % { f($_.projectItems) } } }

$dte.Solution.Projects | % { f($_.ProjectItems) }

function f($projectItems) { $projectItems | ? { $_.Name -ne $null -and $_.Name.EndsWith( ".css" ) -and (-not $_.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.Contains("common")) -and (-not $_.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.Contains("Content")) -and (-not $_.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.Contains("Scripts")) } | % { $win = $_.Open('{7651A701-06E5-11D1-8EBD-00A0C90F26EA}') ; $win.Activate() ; $DTE.ExecuteCommand('Edit.FormatDocument') } ; if ($projectItems) { $projectItems | % { f($_.projectItems) } } }

$dte.Solution.Projects | % { f($_.ProjectItems) }
```

Answer (score -4):

Goto --> Tools -->> Option -->> TextEditor -->> XAML -->> Formatting -->> Spacing -->> Check the Postion Each Attribute on Separate Line! Thats it

Comment: Huh? I think you've misunderstood my question.