# VB.NET IDE: Refresh code lines

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am using the Find & Replace function frequently, and I don't care about the case.
So I am replacing e. g.

```
"Dim s As String = SomeFunc(SomeArg)"
```

with

```
"dim s as string = somenewfunc(somearg)"
```

The IDE replaces it fine, but it uses my lower case typing.
Only when I change something in that line (for example by adding a space at the end of the line)

```
"dim s as string = somenewfunc(somearg)"
```

, it becomes

```
"Dim s As String = SomeNewFunc(SomeArg)"
```

as it should be.

Does anybody know some magic way to refresh all my lines of code?
Clean and Rebuild did not help me.

Thank you!

Comment: You broke it with find and replace, fix it with find and replace, this time use correct case.  Just a suggestion.  Also Visual Studio has really good support for renaming.  ReSharper has even more support.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

1. When you do your replace use the proper case.
2. You could also do Format Document. Edit --> Advanced --> Format Document or Ctrl E, D But this will only do the current document. Not sure if this will fix your case in the document. Maybe there is a way to do this to all documents, I am not sure. I imagine resharper can do this with code cleanup.
3. You might want to look at the advice from this link:

[How to format all files in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458332/how-to-format-all-files-in-visual-studio-2012)

See Jay Bazuzi's answer.

You will want to tweak his code to use .vb instead of .cs